# Getting object reference not set to an instance in PLINQ forall loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nullpointerexception, plinq, object-reference

I have written a code like following:

```
 newFilteredList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(60).ForAll(qqmethod =>
{
    var xdocic = new XmlDocument();
    xdocic.LoadXml(SendRequest(null, null, qqmethod.ItemID, true, TotalDaysSinceLastUpdate.ToString(), null));
    int TotalPages = 0;
    if (xdocic.GetElementsByTagName("TotalNumberOfPages").Item(0) != null)
    {
        TotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(xdocic.GetElementsByTagName("TotalNumberOfPages").Item(0).InnerText);
    }
    if (TotalPages > 1)
    {
        Parallel.For(1, TotalPages + 1, i =>
        {

            Products.Add(//Add something here);

        });
    }
    else
    {
        Products.Add(//add omething here);
    }
});
```

The line where I get error is the following:

```
 var xdocic = new XmlDocument();
 xdocic.LoadXml(SendRequest(null, null, qqmethod.ItemID, true, TotalDaysSinceLastUpdate.ToString(), null));
```

And it says that some of these variables is either null or I'm missing something here.

On a side note, TotalDaysSinceLastUpdate variable is declared just as a regular integer variable, is that why I'm getting this error?

What could it be guys?

Comment: What variable is null?  What does your debugger say?

Comment: @rory.ap I couldn't tell by looking at it because the exception occured while the app was running as standalone exe...

Comment: @rory.ap do you want me to post the stacktrace?

Comment: Set your debugger to break on managed exceptions...

Comment: No, integer.ToString will never raise this exception, no value type can be a  null-reference. But `qqmethod` can be null, so the item in the list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter should i add check if(qqmethod != null) { // do some stuff here ?}

Comment: @User987: that would be a good idea. Or don't let them into the list in the first place

Comment: @TimSchmelter you're the man ,thanks =)